# MTPHow to Configure Outgoing Email with External SMTP Server

Tags: 2010, email, configuration

My Sharepoint Server is configured to use a local SMTP Server (the server's own IIS 6.0 SMTP virtual server).  The problem with this is that the message headers of these emails don't receive the reverse DNS information, but I actually have a real mail server running (hMailServer) and I'd rather use that for smtp, or maybe even gmail.

How can I configure my Portal's outgoing email to use an external smtp server?  I could set a different *Outbound SMTP Server* in SCA's Outgoing Email Settings, but there is nowhere to specify the login password for that server.

Or is there a way to make the local SMTP Virtual Server (in IIS6) to use my real mail server for SMTP?

Comment: This post describes setting up relay to external SMTP server from the default SMTP server on SP server, but I am not sure if this will provide the reverse DNS info u are looking for: http://blogs.technet.com/b/yashgoel-msft/archive/2012/10/26/configuring-outgoing-email-settings-in-sharepoint-with-gmail-smtp.aspx

Comment: Thanks!  Actually, I was just looking at that page...  And I found I already had it configured, but had not set the FQDN correctly, nor added a masquerade domain...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post describes setting up relay to external SMTP server from the default SMTP server (on SharePoint server). Authentication information can be provided while setting up the outbound security:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/yashgoel-msft/archive/2012/10/26/configuring-outgoing-email-settings-in-sharepoint-with-gmail-smtp.aspx

Thanks

Comment: I found it was necessary to set the FQDN in both IIS6 settings AND in SCA's Outgoing Email Settings.  This prevents email servers like google from seeing a mismatch in the domain/sender email headers.